# Vite local server is not opening on the browser

Tags: laravel, npm, vite

I'm using Laravel, added Vite .. but whenever I execute 'run npm dev' it doesn't work (this site can't be reached..). I've also another project with same issue.. Any feedback will be appreciated.

[npm run dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmh5p.png)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mzAX.png)

[2nd project - npm run dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLyuV.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need a separate terminal and run `php artisan serve`
then use the given link there to run your application. `npm run dev` is for the front end for laravel so even you type the given host when you execute the `npm run dev` it will tell you use `php artisan serve` instead. If you are using macOS you should use the [Laravel Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/valet). You can use the `http://appname.test/` as a URL.

Comment: only 'php artisan serve' is working for me, this 'npm run dev' is not working at all. If I open them together, the link given by Vite is not workin. If I open Artisan (alone or together) it works. This making me confused.

Comment: You don't need to open the link given by the `Vite` in the browser the only link you need is the one given by the `php artisan serve`.